# Unlit/Textures вместе с Normal Map

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, blender

Есть ли в Unity шейдер, в котором можно использовать normal map и в то же время источник освещения, как например в unlit/texture?

Comment: На русском пожалуйста, да и куда смотрят модеры)

Comment: Черт, я даже не заметил что оказался на русской версии )